# have additional column in ManyToMany join table in Doctrine (Symfony2)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

#### Situation

I have two entities User and Group with relation ManyToMany. Relation is created as separated table (called `user_group`) with two columns `user_id` and `group_id`.

#### Problem

I want to add one more field `addedOn TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`  to table `user_group`. I do not care that doctrine will not see this column, I could select it via SQL when I need it.

#### Question

Can this be done via **doctrine configuration**? If yes, how?
I know I can just add column in DB but then everytime I generate migration diff there would be SQL statement to delete this column.

#### Relative info

App: Symfony 2.5, Doctrine 2.4.

Relation is defined in configuration as is User.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="RAZ\UserBundle\Entity\Group")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_group",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $groups;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No you can't, to have `ManyToMany` association and additional column in your junction table you need to rewrite your mapping as to have a junction entity between your user and group entity as below

For user your mapping will be like

```
        OneToMany
      ------------>
User          UserHasGroups
      <------------
        ManyToOne
```

Same for group entity

```
        OneToMany
       ----------->
Group          UserHasGroups
       <-----------
        ManyToOne
```

Now you can set your entities as

### User Entity

```
/**
 * User
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_table_name")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\UserHasGroups", mappedBy="users",cascade={"persist","remove"} )
     */
    protected $hasGroups;

}
```

### Group Entity

```
/**
 * Group
 * @ORM\Table(name="group_table_name")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Group 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\UserHasGroups", mappedBy="groups",cascade={"persist","remove"} )
     */
    protected $hasUsers;

}
```

### UserHasGroups Entity

```
/**
 * UserHasGroups
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_groups_table_name")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UserHasGroups
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\Group", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $groups;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist","remove"} ,inversedBy="medias", fetch="LAZY" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
     */
    protected $users;


    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="added_on", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $addedOn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addedOn= new \DateTime('now');
    }

}
```

Now you have mapped your entities you can have your `UserHasGroups` entity use repository method by provide user and group values like `findBy,findAll` etc or if you have user object then you can directly get the `UserHasGroups` object which contains the collection of associations for that user

Comment: If the additional column is "ordered" (in order to have a certain sorting by order) - is there a chance to order per default e.g. the Groups with the help of this additional column?