# Multiple relations in a single Doctrine join table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a table that is related to multiple other tables through a single (!) join table.
Here is a rough sketch:

```
pupils_table  (master table)
---
id  name
```

­

```
teachers_table  (related table 1)
---
id  first_name  last_name  ...
```

­

```
courses_table  (related table 2)
---
id  start_date  end_date  ...
```

­

```
join_table  (relates master to both (!) related tables)
---
id  master_id  teacher_id  course_id
```

A standard SQL query to get full pupil records with their teachers and courses would be:

```
select p.*, t.*, c.* from pupils_table p 
left join join_table jt on jt.master_id = p.id
inner join teachers_table t on t.id = jt.teacher_id
inner join courses_table  c on c.id = jt.courses_id
;
```

But I have a hard time to create such a query using Doctrine's relation mapping and QueryBuilder. All examples that I find use a join table that relates a master table to only one related table.

Here is what I tried in the entity if my master:

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="pupils_table")
*/
class Pupils
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Teachers")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="join_table",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="master_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="teacher_id", referencedColumnName="id")}     * )
     */
    private $teachers;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Courses")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="join_table",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="master_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id")}     * )
     */
    private $courses;

    ...
```

I did not introduce any special relations in the Teachers and Courses entities so far.

My query build looks like this:

```
    $qb->select('p', 't', 'c')
        ->from('AppBundle:Pupils', 'p')
        ->innerJoin('p.teachers', 't')
        ->innerJoin('p.courses', 'c')
    ;

    $res = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The result is a weired SQL query with a wrong inner join sequence an the result does not nest the related data correctly (which is to be expected with this SQL):

```
SELECT ... FROM pupils_table c0_
INNER JOIN join_table c3_ ON c0_.id = c3_.master_id 
INNER JOIN teachers_table c1_ ON c1_.id = c3_.teacher_id 
INNER JOIN join_table c4_ ON c0_.id = c4_.master_id 
INNER JOIN courses_table c2_ ON c2_.id = c4_.course_id
```

As you can see, there is no left join preceding the inner joins and also the join_table is joined twice. I understand that I did not explicitly add a left join in my QueryBuilder commands, but how could I if the join table is only mentioned in the DocBlock annotations and does not have an entity of its own (which is what the docs tell me).

Answer (score 0):

To implement such type of mapping i would go for junction entity which will hold the references to these 3 entities and that structure will generate the right SQL which you have mentioned in your post. Below is the explanation of how we can create and relate junction entity

First don't directly link these 3 entities instead link your junction entity with these 3 in below way

```
PupilTeacherCourseHasMany ---ManyToOne---> Pupils
PupilTeacherCourseHasMany ---ManyToOne---> Teachers
PupilTeacherCourseHasMany ---ManyToOne---> Courses

Pupils ---OneToMany---> PupilTeacherCourseHasMany
Teachers ---OneToMany---> PupilTeacherCourseHasMany
Courses---OneToMany---> PupilTeacherCourseHasMany
```

**Pupils Class**

```
/**
 * Pupils
 * @ORM\Table(name="pupils")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Pupils
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\PupilTeacherCourseHasMany", mappedBy="pupils",cascade={"your options"} )
     */
    protected $pupilTeacherCourseHasMany;

}
```

**Teachers Class**

```
/**
 * Teachers
 * @ORM\Table(name="teachers")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Teachers
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\PupilTeacherCourseHasMany", mappedBy="teachers",cascade={"your options"} )
     */
    protected $pupilTeacherCourseHasMany;

}
```

**Courses Class**

```
/**
 * Courses
 * @ORM\Table(name="courses")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Courses
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\PupilTeacherCourseHasMany", mappedBy="courses",cascade={"your options"} )
     */
    protected $pupilTeacherCourseHasMany;

}
```

**PupilTeacherCourseHasMany**

```
/**
 * PupilTeacherCourseHasMany
 * @ORM\Table(name="pupilteachercoursehasmany")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PupilTeacherCourseHasMany
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\Pupils", cascade={"your options"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pupil_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $pupils;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\Teachers", cascade={"your options"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="teacher_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $teachers;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\Courses", cascade={"your options"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $courses;
}
```

Now to get all details your doctrine query will be some thing like

```
$qb->select('p', 't', 'c')
    ->from('AppBundle:Pupils', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('AppBundle:PupilTeacherCourseHasMany ptc')
    ->innerJoin('ptc.teachers', 't')
    ->innerJoin('ptc.courses', 'c')
;
$res = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

[For reference see my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739592/have-additional-column-in-manytomany-join-table-in-doctrine-symfony2/25743327#25743327)

Comment: OR this `->leftJoin('AppBundle:PupilTeacherCourseHasMany ptc')` can be changed to `->leftJoin('p.pupilTeacherCourseHasMany','ptc')`