# Symfony: ManyToMany table extra columns

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have a many to many table for `User` and `House`, called `user_house`. Instead of just two columns: user_id and house_id, i want to add 3 more: eg action, created_at, updated_at. How can I do this?

I cannot find any relevant docs on this.

The following just creates a separate table with two columns in it.

```
class User extends EntityBase
{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\House")
     */
    protected $action;
```

Basically, what I want to achieve is:

in the `user_house` table the combination of `user_id`, `house_id`, `action` should be unique.

when a user clicks a "view" on a house, user_house table gets updated with `some user_id`, `some house_id`, `view`, `now()`, `now()`

when a user clicks a "like" on a house, user_house table gets updated with `some user_id`, `some house_id`, `like`, `now()`, `now()`

when a user clicks a "request a call" on a house, user_house table gets updated with `some user_id`, `some house_id`, `contact`, `now()`, `now()`

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: You must create third entity (ie. UserHouse) with `OneToMany` relation to `User` and `OneToMany` relation to `House` and `action` field. To avoid duplications add unique index (User, House).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to break your `ManyToMany` relation to `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` by introducing a junction entity called as `UserHasHouses`, This way you could add multiple columns to your junction table `user_house`

### User Entity

```
/**
 * User
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\UserHasHouses", mappedBy="users",cascade={"persist","remove"} )
     */
    protected $hasHouses;

}
```

### House Entity

```
/**
 * Group
 * @ORM\Table(name="house")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class House
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\UserHasHouses", mappedBy="houses",cascade={"persist","remove"} )
     */
    protected $hasUsers;

}
```

### UserHasHouses Entity

```
/**
 * UserHasHouses 
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_house")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UserHasHouses 
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\House", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="house_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $houses;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist","remove"}, fetch="LAZY" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
     */
    protected $users;


    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $createdAt;


    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $updatedAt;
     //... add other properties
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createdAt= new \DateTime('now');
    }

}
```

[have additional column in ManyToMany join table in Doctrine (Symfony2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739592/have-additional-column-in-manytomany-join-table-in-doctrine-symfony2/25743327#25743327)

Comment: @Khalid Can you please also let me know how I can make a group of {user_id, house_id, action} primary (or unique). As in, there cannot be a duplicate of all three of them, like `1,1,view` and then another `1,1,view` but it can be `1,2,view`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NodirRashidov you could define `@UniqueEntity` annotation in your `UserHasHouses Entity` for multiple properties please have a look at [UniqueEntity Annotation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#errorpath). In your case it would be like `fields={"houses", "users", "action"},`

Comment: I was trying this yesterday but i was using the column names (`{house_id , user_id, action}`) instead and it was not working. I will try with the variable names and write back in 20minutes. thanks!

Comment: @NodirRashidov yes you have to use property names not column names

Comment: I had to also add this to the `* @ORM\Table(...)` annotation: `* @ORM\Table(name="user_house",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="user_house_action", columns={"user_id", "house_id", "action"})})` , otherwise the mysql table would not make a group of primary keys. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have one more question. Sorry to be bothering you so much. When I want to persist data to this kind of relationship entitty, instead of `$em->persist($data)` should I be using a different approach with innerJoin() ?

Comment: @NodirRashidov it isn't much clear from your comment if `$data` is instance of UserHasHouses then yes you can use persist , I didn't get the inner join part . Also if you have some query or problem can always ask a new question