# symfony entities many to many, i add new fields

Tags: php, symfony

I try this code:  [Symfony: ManyToMany table extra columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344073/symfony-manytomany-table-extra-columns/50344465#50344465)

This new field is because the user have a diferent role for diferent events.

In the fist time i can add add the new fields on table user.evento, but now i cant. And i dont find the problem.

I get this fail:

**An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user_evento (user_id, evento_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [3, 18]: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'tipoinvitado' doesn't have a default value**

why not detecting the other 2 fields ?

capture of my sql update with the new fields

[image: capture]

**my entity UserHasEvento:**

```
 
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="user_evento")
*/
class UserHasEvento
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   private $id;
 
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Evento", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="evento_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $eventos;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", cascade={"persist","remove"}, fetch="LAZY" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="tipoinvitado", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $tipoinvitado;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fechainscripcion", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $fechainscripcion;    

    public function setTipoinvitado(string $tipoinvitado): self
    {
        $this->tipoinvitado = $tipoinvitado;
 
        return $this;
    }
 
    public function getTipoinvitado(): string
    {
        return $this->tipoinvitado;
    }

    public function getFechainscripcion()
    {
        return $this->fechainscripcion;
    }

    public function setFechainscripcion($fechainscripcion): self
    {
        $this->fechainscripcion = $fechainscripcion;

        return $this;
    }  
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createdAt= new \DateTime('now');
    }
}
```

**My controller update.**

```
  public function asignarUsuario(Request $request, Evento $evento, Userhasevento $userhasevento){
        $user_repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
        $users = $user_repo->findAll();    

        $evento = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Evento::class)->findOneById($evento); 
        $form = $this->createForm(AsignarEventoFormType::class, $evento);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $users = $evento->GetUsers();
                foreach($users as $user){
               $user->addEvento($evento);       
                $evento->addUser($user);
                $userhasevento->SetTipoinvitado('normal');
                $userhasevento->setFechainscripcion(new \DateTime('now'));
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($evento);
                $em->persist($userhasevento);
                $em->flush();
            }
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('evento_detalle', ['id' => $evento->getId()]));
 
        }        
        return $this->render('evento/AsignarEvento.html.twig',[
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your field $tipoinvitado disappear?
You might have changed your relation and the null boolean of $tipoinvitado at some point. You made your migration after changing any relation?

This can happen when you change your relations and had already data stored in you DB in a field that disappear because of you relation change.

I might be able to help you, don't hesitate giving more info

Comment: $tipoinvitado disappear, the field on my entity is the same on my sql , on my entity i change $tipoinvitado  for true, and i get the same error

Comment: Did you store data on your database before the field disappear? If was the case it means that you new change is having a conflict with the old parameters. The changed you made was made by hand? or you deleted the field and recreated a new one with the right value?

Comment: yes, i add fields before disappear, i add the news fields by hands. But late, i can add news dates on table, but now, i cant. I dont think who is the problem, because when the doctrine try inject dates , dont detect the news fields, for example $tipoinvitado

Comment: Hablas español? Si es el caso. Creo que el problema es cuando agregaste campos a la mano. Esto hace que tu base de datos no los reconozca. Mi consejo es que borres el campo $tipoinvitado y lo agregues en el terminal y luego hagas tú migración para que tu base de datos hagas las modificaciones necesarias.

Comment: sii !! osea que deje la tabla como estaba en la base de datos y haga la migracion desde symfony para que añada esos campos? pero esque me parece extraño porque antes si los metia, pero empece a meter la fecha y desde entonces empezo a fallar todo, bueno probare eso que me dices.

Comment: Si. Borra tu campo $tipoinvitado de tu código y vuelves a crearla con Entity:make y luego migras. A veces depende de tu relación también. Hay relaciones que te quitan el campo de algunas entidades por qué crean colecciones en las entidades a las que están relacionadas. En tal caso de que sea tu relación que te quita el campo $tipoinvitado entonces puedes crear la relación pero en el sentido contrario. Tuve ese problema hace poco y pasé mucho tiempo para entenderlo. Espero que solo agregando el campo de nuevo tu problema se resuelva

Comment: el problema esque, me salta con :   The table with name 'eventos.user_evento' already exists.

borro la tabla en la base de datos y me sigue dando el mismo fallo.

Comment: Cuando haces tus migraciones ejecutas primero symfony console make:migration y luego symfony console migration:migrate?

Comment: Intenta revisar y re-estudiar bien la estructura de la relacion de tus entidades. Creo que tu problema puede venir de como hiciste las relaciones entre entidades. Crear un relacion que va en el sentido user=>user_evento es muy diferente a una relacion en el sentido contrario user_evento=>user . Asi sea el mismo tipo de relacion (ManyToOne o OneToMany o ManyToMany etc...)

Comment: Ya lo solucione ! :D no era nada de la base de datos, era de las entidades. Igualmente tuve que cambiar parte del codigo del controlador.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda :D

Comment: De nada. Justamente hace algunos dias termine de desarrollar un proyecto en symfony y encontre el mismo tipo de problemas con las entidades y relaciones

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in the error, the `$tipoinvitado` field has the annotation `nullable=false` which is a **not null constraint** (prevent storing null value), so it should absolutely have a value.
So you either give it a default value, give a value or change it to `nullable=true`.