# Can't add a new ManyToMany property between entity A to B because I already have a ManyToMany property with both these entity

Tags: php, database, symfony, many-to-many

So basically title. I'm building a music player and I would like it so that my Songs have 2 property : artists and collab-artists.

I have a Song entity which has an "artists" relational ManyToMany property where I can link 1 (or more) Artist entity to the Song. I would like to have another relational ManyToMany property "collab-artists" with Song and Artist.

I can `php bin/console make:entity` to create the collab-artist property but when I `php bin/console make:migration` I get :

**In SchemaException.php line 112: The table with name 'banana.song_artist' already exists.**

Seems like symfony is trying to create a table to store the relationship, but it is already used. How can I tell it to create another table with a different name ?

Thanks,
Maxence

EDIT : I ended up using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/50344465/16267883

Which explodes the relation between 3 tables, **Song** > *OneToMany* > **SongHasArtist** > *ManyToOne* > **Artist**

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the name of the join table by using the `@ORM/JoinTable` annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Artist", inversedBy="songs")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="songs_collab_artists")
 */
private $collabArtists;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer  ! 
I ended up using this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50344465/16267883

Comment: What if I want to use the same table but for two different columns? Using `@JoinTable` on both `@ManyToMany` properties gives me error that table already exists, so how can I tell Doctrine to not create the table again, just use it?