# Doctrine, how pass additional values to junction table row in case ManyToMany relation?

Tags: php, doctrine, many-to-many, legacy

I refactoring now legacy application, including moving database code to doctrine.

My case: I have three entities, Headquarters, RegionalOffice, and RegionalManager. RegionalManager is both junction table for ManytoMany and info about regional manager intself and this entity have not just links to Headquarters and RegionalOffice, but also a lot other not null properties.

If i try:

```
$headquarters->addRegionalOffice($office);
```

Doctrine unable create RegionalManager because of his name, for example.

So my question, can I pass additional information for junction record, name, address, age etc?

Comment: You dont have many-to-many but rather 3 entities in a structure like that: `Headquarters` <- OneToMany -> `RegionalManager` <- ManyToOne -> `RegionalOffice`?
Then if you want to add new `RegionalOffice` create it `new RegionalOffice()` create `new RegionalManager()`. Set both RegionalOffice and Headquarters in RegionalManager and prsist both entities?

Comment: [have additional column in ManyToMany join table in Doctrine (Symfony2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739592/have-additional-column-in-manytomany-join-table-in-doctrine-symfony2/25743327#25743327) this will help you to introduce intermediate entity to handle additional columns in a many-to-many relation